# Magento Template

Tags: php, html, magento

I have been asked by a customer to edit there ecommerce website, the cms system they use is Magento, how would i go about changing the category page html coding as i need to change a h2 to a h1. Were is it stored on the FTP so i can download edit html and then reupload.

Thanks