# Change Magento Template

Tags: html, magento, php

I have been asked by a customer to edit there ecommerce website, the cms system they use is Magento, how would i go about changing the category page html coding as i need to change a h2 to a h1. Were is it stored on the FTP so i can download edit html and then reupload. i have tried to go to `/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/mylightbulb/template/catalog/category` and the view.phtml does not contain the html i am after

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735490/magento-template)

Comment: This would be more appropriate to post as part of your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735490/magento-template) which you only asked a half hour before this one.

Comment: Questions merged into this one.  @user you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4735940/edit) this question if you need to add detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento's template is quite complicated (but flexible), but one way to find out where the HTML for a 'block' is located is by [enabling Template Path Hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/).

Comment: Do the template hints provide the path you mentioned above? You might need to refresh the cache to have the proper path displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit their theme file for the category page here

/app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

Comment: when i get to the folder "frontend" i only have base and default folders not themepackage

Comment: base and default are the theme packages I put that there since you might have it set as something else. go to frontend default most likely